# My borders don't line up?

Tags: html, navigationbar

I have the following navigation bar in HTML5:

```
<div id = 'nav'>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href = ''>HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class = 'final_nav'>
            <a href = ''>FAQ</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Styled with this CSS:

```
#nav {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0.1px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
}
#nav li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline;
}
.final_nav {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
#nav a {
    display: block-inline;
}
```

But the left & right borders don't align with the top & bottom ones:
[image: Navigation Bar]
Why is this?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#nav li {
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 17px;
    display: inline;
}
```

This should fix it.